# How do I mention only the major highways as output rather than local roads?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-directions-api

I am using Directions API to get a route segment (list of destinations to reach a particular destination).

```
origin = "New York"
destination = "Ohio"
output: ['2 Murray Street, New York, NY 10007, USA', '50 14th St, Jersey City, NJ 07310, USA', '5710 Newark - Jersey City Tpke, Kearny, NJ 07032, USA', 'US 46, 07058, , New Jersey, United States', '192 Waring Dr, Delaware Water Gap, PA 18327, USA', '4891 E County Line Rd, Mineral Ridge, OH 44440, USA', ', 44451, , Ohio, United States', '914&, 916 Rosamond Ave, Akron, OH 44307, USA', '1090 W Wilbeth Rd, Akron, OH 44314, USA', 'US 224, 44273, , Ohio, United States', 'I 71, 43334, , Ohio, United States', '3970 OH-229, Marengo, OH 43334, USA', '2390 OH-229, Ashley, OH 43003, USA']
```

the desired output: The above list shows each and every address I need to go through to reach Ohio from New York. I wish to get only the HIGHWAY/EXPRESSWAY/MAJOR ROADS

I have an origin and a destination. I wish to get a list of Highways which I have to take in order to reach the destination from the origin (mode=driving).

Comment: Welcome ! your question is not clear. Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There's no such feature in the Directions API

While it is possible to **avoid highways**, it is not possible to **prioritize highways** as of writing this as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#avoid).

Directions API can force the route for which it returns a distance not to take any highways, but the opposite is not true. In other words, there's no option to make the API only return routes through highways.

What I could suggest as a workaround is that you use waypoints on **Directions API** to **manually force the API to use a highway** by making the route go through coordinates of your choice, though it'd be a more manual process. You can read more on waypoints here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#waypoints

Another thing I would like to suggest is for you to file **Feature Request** in the **Public Issue Tracker** and add your use case that might help Google Engineers consider such feature. Here's a link that would help you get started: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Please note that a Google Public Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding the feature request that you'll post, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there.

> Note: *It would also be great if you can edit your question and link the Feature Request you filed/will file here.*

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I looked up, there is a result part known as 'summary' when you extract the result after processing. It gives the name of major highway.

Comment: Great! If this answer was able to help, the community would appreciate it if you can upvote and accept this to help others encountering the same issue in the future. Thanks